# getting detailed error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: ajax, web-services, asmx, webmethod

i create a Web Method in .asmx file and hosted it on server,when i'm calling it from any remote application that time i'm getting this error:

```
 detailed error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

my WebMethod .cs code is as:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string UserLogin(string u_name,string user_pwd)
    {
        string result = "true";
        if (u_name == "unicolumn" && user_pwd=="admin")
        {
            result = "true";
        }

    else
        {
            result = "false";

        }
        return result;

    }
```

and my ajax call method is here:

```
function apiLogin()
{
var UserName = document.getElementById('txtUserName').value;
var PWD = document.getElementById('txtUserPWD').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.200.55/ChatApp.asmx/UserLogin",
    data: {u_name:UserName,user_pwd:PWD},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
           alert(response);
        },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
 }
```

when i'm testing it by running visual studio application it is working fine, in case of calling it from another application, generating an error
can someone please help me to figure out what i'm missing here.... thanks in advance.